# jQuery, AJAX, PHP, and receiving info

Tags: jquery

I am not familiar with jQuery and searching gave me answers very different than what I was looking for.

I am using ajax to load data from a PHP script that loads from a database. I want to load new data and not load old data that is already displayed. I came up with the idea of using the highest index value from the table I am pulling data from to do this, easy enough. Doing it in PHP is no problem but getting a loop going is the difficult part.

My PHP script outputs HTML that is pasted in the receiving page. I need that page to receive a variable from my page so on the next request it can submit the highest index value to prevent duplicates. Now that is where the problem lies.

The jQuery AJAX receives datatype 'HTML'. How do I pass a variable along with the HTML so the script can be updated.

Summary of how program works:

```
-Page.php sends an ajax(GET) request to script.php with a few variables
-Script.php receives the request and processes the variables
-Script.php finishes processing and outputs HTML
-(I want script.php to send variables to page.php that can be identified separately from the HTML)
-Page.php receives HTML and appends it
-(I want those variables to be added to the Jquery variables so they can be sent on next request)
```

Now how to do this is the problem. I am not too familiar with jQuery so I am not sure if it can be done normally.

Comment: What code do you have so far?  What's the problem?  Getting the right data, rendering it to the page, or both?

Comment: Right now I can submit data and receive data from that Ajax request and it works fine. I am just trying to figure out how to receive a variable with that AJAX request, apart from the HTML data. 

The end result of the AJAX(GET) request is properly formatted HTML. I need a variable sent along with it. That or I need to figure out a different method for handling this.

Comment: @Rujikin .. please post your code and put extra effort in your question .. thats the only way that you show that you want to solve a problem in here , other wise you wont get that much attention ...

Comment: @codiezNone of my code relates to this problem because I am not sure how to start coding this. The rest of my code works fine and without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the markup for the items isnt complex i would normally get the data as json and then make the markup in js.

For example lets say this is the json data we get back:

```
{
   "offset": 0,
   "limit": 5,
   "results": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "something"},
      { "id": 2, "name": "something2"},
      { "id": 3, "name": "something3"},
      { "id": 4, "name": "something4"},
      { "id": 5, "name": "something5"}
   ]
}
```

We can use `offset` and `limit` as a one-to-one for the SQL of the data to which this response corresponds. So that makes the jquery something like this:

```
function getResults(limit, offset) {
    $.getJSON('getitems.php', {'limit': 5, 'offset': 0}, function(data){
       var tpl = '<div id="result-_ID_">_NAME_</div>',
           html = '';  
       if(data.results.length > 0) {
         $.each(data.results, function(i, obj){
             html += tpl.replace('_ID_', obj.id).replace('_NAME_', obj.name);
         });

         $(elementToAppendTo).append(html);

         // there could be more left so lets do it again, with the offset incremented
         // to get the next set ie. offset = 0+5 = 5
         getResults(data.limit, data.offset+data.limit);
       }
    });
}
```

Of course this example would jsut keep calling itself and i assume you want some user action to determin when to make the call for the next set of items but this shoudl illustrate the general idea.

Comment: Hum... I was wondering if you could do something like this as an alternative. I could do a max function on the JSON array and get the highest ID value, I could submit older info with special handling tags, and this solves a few problems I would have to deal with in the future. Thanks! Guess I am going to have to learn a lot more about Jquery and JSON data XD